# Can I run a new independently-switched light from a box in a four-way switch circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, junction-box

I'm doing some renovating and where I want to put a closet I'd like to put a light. There is a junction box there which appears to have been used as a light before and would be ideal. It has only 1 3-wire coming in and 1 out, twisted together. They moved the light elsewhere. I'm hoping I can use this box for a light with its own switch and somehow get power from it.

So the current configuration goes like this:

```
 Light 
  ||
  ||
Switch 1
  |||
  |||
 J-box (old light box?)
  |||
  |||
Switch 2
  |||
  |||
Switch 3 (power)
```

2-wire from the light to the first switch. 3-wire from that switch to the junction box and 3-wire to 2 other switches. Power comes in at Switch 3. Can I get power from this box or do I have to use a new line?

Comment: @isherwood I've edited to show power comes from the last switch, Switch 3. It appears that there are 3 outlets and two other lights on the same circuit.

Comment: What do those switches control? Can any of the three turn the light on or off? -- Also, look at the switches and the connections in the boxes. It looks like switch 2 is a "four-way", ie. it has four terminals (besides the ground).

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Each switch can turn light on/off. Yes Switch 2 is a "four-way". Switch 1 and Switch 3 are "three-way".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have enough conductors in those cables to add a constantly powered device at the j-box. You would have to either run another wire from switch 1 to the j-box, or abandon the use of switches 2 and 3 and control the existing light with switch 1 only.

Answer (score 1):

The day is saved by smart switches.

In this case, you reconfigure the circuit for an appropriate smart switch.  Locate a "master" smart switch at switch 1, and smart switch remotes in 2 and 3.  The 3 wires (besides ground) become

- neutral (white)
- always-hot (black?)
- communications line  (red?)

The cable to the lamp is switched-hot and neutral, of course.

Now you can tap always-hot and neutral for a lamp, and either have a pull cord at the lamp, or branch off a new switch loop.  Remember switch loops must now be wired in /3 cable and provide a neutral.